# Grouping pandas DataFrame with Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have this in a `pandas` DataFrame:

```
+-------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------+--------+--------------+
| Family            | Genus           | Species  | hasHair | laysEggs | canFly | hasLongHorns |
+-------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------+--------+--------------+
| Bovidae           | Ovis            | Sheep    |    1    |     0    |    0   |       0      |
+-------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------+--------+--------------+
| Passeroidea       | Passeridae      | Sparrow  |    0    |     1    |    1   |       0      |
+-------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------+--------+--------------+
| Ornithorhynchidae | Ornithorhynchus | Platypus |    1    |     1    |    0   |       0      |
+-------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------+--------+--------------+
| Bovidae           | Ovis            | Mouflon  |    1    |     0    |    0   |       1      |
+-------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------+--------+--------------+
| Passeroidea       | Passeridae      | Passer   |    0    |     1    |    1   |       0      |
+-------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------+--------+--------------+
```

I would like to "summarize" the data to obtain the following:

```
+-------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------+--------+--------------+
| Family            | Genus           | Species  | hasHair | laysEggs | canFly | hasLongHorns |
+-------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------+--------+--------------+
| Bovidae           | Ovis            | Sheep    |    1    |     0    |    0   |       0      |
+-------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------+--------+--------------+
|                   |                 | Mouflon  |    1    |     0    |    0   |       1      |
+-------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------+--------+--------------+
| Ornithorhynchidae | Ornithorhynchus | Platypus |    1    |     1    |    0   |       0      |
+-------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------+--------+--------------+
| Passeroidea       | Passeridae      | Sparrow  |    0    |     1    |    1   |       0      |
+-------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------+--------+--------------+
|                   |                 | Passer   |    0    |     1    |    1   |       0      |
+-------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------+--------+--------------+
```

As you can see, this is more layout to enhance readability than actual data processing: the values of the properties are unchanged. I just want to produce a report that can be easier to read.

Now, I'm not sure how to tackle this. Can anyone offer some pointers?

Thanks!

R.

Answer (score 2):

For easier read you can create `MultiIndex` and sorting it:

```
df = df.set_index(['Family','Genus', 'Species']).sort_index()
```

Comment: Ah yes, even simpler than I thought! :-) Thank you!